# Expand ICD10 codes from one row into multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning, icd

I have a dataset like this:

| ICD_10 | diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| A00 | Cholera |
| A01-A03 | Other Intestinal infectious diseases |
| A15 | Respiratory tuberculosis |
| A17-A19 | Other tuberculosis |

...

On row 2 and 4, there are multiple ICD-10 codes, and I want to expand them into multiple rows, like below:

| ICD_10 | diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| A00 | Cholera |
| A01 | Other Intestinal infectious diseases |
| A02 | Other Intestinal infectious diseases |
| A03 | Other Intestinal infectious diseases |
| A15 | Respiratory tuberculosis |
| A17 | Other tuberculosis |
| A18 | Other tuberculosis |
| A19 | Other tuberculosis |

How can I accomplish this in R using tidyverse?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it always the case that the letter in a range is the same letter? For instance, one would never see `A01-B05`?

Comment: @r2evans - if it's ICD-10 coding, I don't think you should see that sort of thing. You do however see instances like H10-H13 only having H10, H11 and H13, no H12.

Comment: @thelatemail, it sounds like you and the OP know what `ICD_10` means, it is not obvious what constraints or standards for it may exist.

Comment: @thelatemail looks like there is a dedicated packages for this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
fun <- function(vec) {
  ltr <- substring(vec, 1, 1)
  L <- lapply(strsplit(gsub("[^-0-9]", "", vec), "-"), as.integer)
  mapply(function(ltr, z) sprintf("%s%02i", ltr, if (length(z) > 1) seq(z[1], z[2]) else z),
         ltr, L)
}
quux %>%
  mutate(ICD_10 = fun(ICD_10)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(ICD_10)
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
#   ICD_10 diagnosis                           
#   <chr>  <chr>                               
# 1 A00    Cholera                             
# 2 A01    Other Intestinal infectious diseases
# 3 A02    Other Intestinal infectious diseases
# 4 A03    Other Intestinal infectious diseases
# 5 A15    Respiratory tuberculosis            
# 6 A17    Other tuberculosis                  
# 7 A18    Other tuberculosis                  
# 8 A19    Other tuberculosis
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(ICD_10 = c("A00", "A01-A03", "A15", "A17-A19"), diagnosis = c("Cholera", "Other Intestinal infectious diseases", "Respiratory tuberculosis", "Other tuberculosis")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks! it works on my data.

Answer (score 2):

Using dedicated [icd package](https://github.com/jackwasey/icd/):

```
#data
d <- structure(list(ICD_10 = c("A00", "A01-A03", "A15", "A17-A19"), diagnosis = c("Cholera", "Other Intestinal infectious diseases", "Respiratory tuberculosis", "Other tuberculosis")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

#remotes::install_github("jackwasey/icd")
library(icd)
```

To avoid creating non-existent or missing out existing codes between the ranges we use *expand_ranges*. For example, below returns 33 codes, instead of 3 if we filled in sequentially A01, A02, A03, which is wrong.

```
expand_range("A01", "A03")
#  [1] "A01"   "A010"  "A0100" "A0101" "A0102" "A0103" "A0104" "A0105"
#  [9] "A0109" "A011"  "A012"  "A013"  "A014"  "A02"   "A020"  "A021" 
# [17] "A022"  "A0220" "A0221" "A0222" "A0223" "A0224" "A0225" "A0229"
# [25] "A028"  "A029"  "A03"   "A030"  "A031"  "A032"  "A033"  "A038" 
# [33] "A039"
```

We also use *explain_code*, to give description for newly created codes, example usage:

```
explain_code("A01")
# [1] "Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers"
```

Now, wrap two functions into one, to get a pretty output

```
# custom function using expand_range
f <- function(icd10, diagnosis){
  x <- unlist(strsplit(icd10, "-"))
  
  if(length(x) == 1){ ICD10 = x 
  } else {ICD10 = expand_range(x[1], x[2])}
  
  data.frame(
    icd10 = icd10,
    diagnosis = diagnosis, 
    icd10range = ICD10,
    desc = explain_code(ICD10))
}
```

And loop through the codes to expand, then rowbind:

```
# loop through rows, and rowbind
res <- do.call(rbind, 
               mapply(f, d$ICD_10, d$diagnosis,
                      SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE))

head(res)
#     icd10                            diagnosis icd10range                                 desc
# 1     A00                              Cholera        A00                              Cholera
# 2 A01-A03 Other Intestinal infectious diseases        A01       Typhoid and paratyphoid fevers
# 3 A01-A03 Other Intestinal infectious diseases       A010                        Typhoid fever
# 4 A01-A03 Other Intestinal infectious diseases      A0100           Typhoid fever, unspecified
# 5 A01-A03 Other Intestinal infectious diseases      A0101                   Typhoid meningitis
# 6 A01-A03 Other Intestinal infectious diseases      A0102 Typhoid fever with heart involvement
```

As expected A01-A03 now expanded into 33 rows:

```
table(res$icd10)
# A00 A01-A03     A15 A17-A19 
#   1      33       1      53
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```r
tibble::tribble(
  ~ICD_10, ~diagnosis,
  "A00", "Cholera",
  "A01-A03", "Other Intestinal infectious diseases",
  "A15", "Respiratory tuberculosis",
  "A17-A19", "Other tuberculosis"
) |> 
  tidyr::separate_rows(ICD_10, sep = "-") |> 
  mutate(id = parse_number(ICD_10)) |> 
  group_by(diagnosis) |> 
  complete(id = min(id):max(id)) |> 
  mutate(ICD_10 = paste0("A", id))
```

Comment: To make it use the letter from the code (when not necessarily A), you could replace last line with: `tidyr::fill(ICD_10) %>% mutate(ICD_10 = paste0(substr(ICD_10, 1, 1), id))`